# Открывание окок(переход между ними), учусь разбираться в классах

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

Набросал небольшую прогу, на основе учебника. Приложение, которое будет управлять бд.

**Вопрос 1**
Почему в функцию(open или openZvuk) нам нужно передавать self, ведь по сути я просто создаю объект другого класса

**Вопрос 2**
После нажатия на кнопку, которая открывает третье окно ( `class WindowZvuk`) просто мгновенно закрывается и консоль пишет рестарт и ничего не происходит. Пробовал отладить этот фрагмент просто, без создания класса, всё отлично работает. Из этого стоит вывод, что я накосячил в создании класса или чём-то подобном, но сам разобраться не могу.

За критику и подсказки буду благодарен, только начал изучать

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtSql, QtCore
import sys

class Windows(QtWidgets.QWidget):# класс окна "Студия звукозаписи"
    def __init__(self, parent = None):#parent = None for works 
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)# for works
        btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Просмотреть таблицы")
        self.resize(400, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Студия звукозаписи")
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(btn1)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        btn1.clicked.connect(self.open)

    def open(self):
        self.Twowin = Window2()
        self.Twowin.show()
        self.hide()

                 
class Window2(QtWidgets.QWidget):# класс окна "Выбор таблиц"
     def __init__(self, parent = None):#parent = None for works 
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)# for works
        self.resize(400, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Выбор таблиц")
        btnTableZvuk = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Таблица Звукорежиссёров")
        vbox2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox2.addWidget(btnTableZvuk)
        self.setLayout(vbox2)
        btnTableZvuk.clicked.connect(self.openZvuk)

     def openZvuk(self):
         self.WindowZv = WindowZvuk()# вот тут проверить, как рабоатет self.
         self.WindowZv.show()
     
     
 class WindowZvuk(QtWidgets.QWidget):# класс окна "Выбор таблиц"
     def __init__(self, parent = None):#parent = None for works 
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)# for works
        self.resize(1000, 1000)
        con = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        con.setDatabaseName('путь')#здесь специально нет пути, в оригинале он есть
        con.open()
        stm = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(parent = WindowZv)
        stm.setTable('ZvukRez')
        stm.setSort(1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        stm.select()
        stm.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Столбец 1')
        stm.setHeaderData(2, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Столбец 2')
        stm.setHeaderData(3, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Столбец 3j')
        stm.setHeaderData(4, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Столбец 4')       
        stm.setHeaderData(5, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Столбец 5')
        vbox3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        tv = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        tv.setmodel(stm)
        tv.hideColumn(0)
        tv.setColumnWidth(1, 150)
        tv.setColumnWidth(2, 150)
        tv.setColumnWidth(3, 150)
        tv.setColumnWidth(4, 150)
        tv.setColumnWidth(5, 150)
        vbox3.addWidget(tv)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox3)
    

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
MainWindow = Windows()
MainWindow.show()

app.exec()
```

Comment: Если какой либо ответ решил вашу проблему, не забывайте отмечать его как правильный.

Answer (score 1):

> Вопрос 1 Почему в функцию(open или openZvuk) нам нужно передавать self, ведь по
>   сути я просто создаю объект другого класса

`self` в методе и будет являться ссылкой на объект класса. Создадите два объекта и у них вызовите метод, и их ссылки будут переданы в метод как `self`. Это явный указатель на объект класса в методах класса. Например, у c++, java, c# это неявно через `this` реализовано

---

> Вопрос 2 После нажатия на кнопку, которая открывает третье окно (
>   class WindowZvuk) просто мгновенно закрывается и консоль пишет рестарт
>   и ничего не происходит. Пробовал отладить этот фрагмент просто, без
>   создания класса, всё отлично работает. Из этого стоит вывод, что я
>   накосячил в создании класса или чём-то подобном, но сам разобраться не
>   могу.

Скорее всего, у вас выбрасывается исключение из-за какой-то ошибки. Думаю, из-за несуществующего пути в `con.setDatabaseName('путь')`.

Добавьте в код строку для отлова не пойманных исключений:

```
def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    quit()


import sys
sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions
```

Или добавьте локальную обработку исключений (`try/except`) в ваши методы, например:

```
 def openZvuk(self):
     try:
         self.WindowZv = WindowZvuk()# вот тут проверить, как рабоатет self.
         self.WindowZv.show()

     except Exception as e:
         QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', str(e))
```

Answer (score 1):

К вышесказанному @gil9red добавлю, чтобы решить второй вопрос вам надо сделать некоторые исправления:

```
#     stm = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(parent = WindowZv)  # ---
      stm = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)               # +++

#     tv.setmodel(stm)                               # ---
      tv.setModel(stm)                               # +++

#     self.setLayout(self.vbox3)                     # ---
      self.setLayout(vbox3))                         # +++
```

И демо пример прилагается, пробуйте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtSql     import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlTableModel 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QTableView, QApplication, QMessageBox, 
                             QMainWindow, QAbstractItemView, QWidget,
                             QPushButton, QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt


class Windows(QWidget):                
    """ класс окна "Студия звукозаписи" """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Windows, self).__init__(parent)

        btn1 = QPushButton("Просмотреть таблицы")
        btn1.clicked.connect(self.open)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(btn1)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def open(self):
        self.Twowin = Window2()
        self.Twowin.show()
        self.hide()


class Window2(QWidget):                
    """ # класс окна "Выбор таблиц" """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(400, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Выбор таблиц")

        btnTableZvuk = QPushButton("Таблица Звукорежиссёров")
        btnTableZvuk.clicked.connect(self.openZvuk)

        vbox2 = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox2.addWidget(btnTableZvuk)
        self.setLayout(vbox2)

    def openZvuk(self):
        self.WindowZv = WindowZvuk()   # вот тут проверить, как рабоатет self.
        self.WindowZv.show()           #

class WindowZvuk(QMainWindow):    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 150)

        self.createConnection()   
        self.fillTable()
        self.createModel()
        self.initUI()

    def createConnection(self):
        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        self.db.setDatabaseName('sports.db')
        if not self.db.open():
            QMessageBox.critical(None, ("Cannot open database"),
                                       ("Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
                                        "This example needs SQLite support. Please read "
                                        "the Qt SQL driver documentation for information "
                                        "how to build it.\n\n"
                                        "Click Cancel to exit."),
                                       QMessageBox.Cancel)
            return False
        return True

    def fillTable(self):
        self.db.transaction()
        query = QSqlQuery()
        query.exec_("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sportsmen;")
        query.exec_("CREATE TABLE sportsmen(id int primary key, "
                    "firstname varchar(20), lastname varchar(20));")
        query.exec_("INSERT INTO sportsmen values(101, 'Roger', 'Federer');")
        query.exec_("INSERT INTO sportsmen values(102, 'Christiano', 'Ronaldo');")
        query.exec_("INSERT INTO sportsmen values(103, 'Ussain', 'Bolt');")
        query.exec_("INSERT INTO sportsmen values(104, 'Sachin', 'Tendulkar');")
        query.exec_("INSERT INTO sportsmen values(105, 'Saina', 'Nehwal');")
        self.db.commit()

    def createModel(self):
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("sportsmen")
        self.model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "id")
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "firstname")
        self.model.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, "lastname")
        self.model.select()

    def initUI(self):
        self.view = QTableView()       
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        mode = QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection
        self.view.setSelectionMode(mode)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view) 

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if (self.db.open()):
            self.db.close()

    # def addRecord():
    #     stm.insertRow(stm.rowCount())

    # def delRecord():
    #     stm.removeRow(tv.currentIndex().row())
    #     stm.select()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Windows()
    MainWindow.resize(400, 300)
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle("Студия звукозаписи")
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]